# Rsync and cp command to copy ".txt" files to single directory (only if already exists)

Tags: find, rsync, cp

I have a directory structure with multiple `.txt` files with multiple directories. I want to copy all these `.txt` files into one particular directory. I have given below my directory structure:

```
Dir_1
    a.txt
    x.doc
    b.txt
Dir_2
    c.txt
Dir_3
    d.txt
    e.txt
    y.doc
```

To copy all `.txt` files into the directory `~/alltxt`, I am using the below `cp` command.

```
find . -name "*.txt" -exec cp {}  ~/alltxt/  \;
```

It just works fine. Now my directory `alltxt` is like below.

```
alltxt
        a.txt
        b.txt
        c.txt
        d.txt
        e.txt
```

But I see that I want to replace ONLY the changed `.txt` files into that folder. So, I came to know that I could do that using `rsync` command like below.

```
find .  -name '*.txt' -exec rsync -R {} ~/alltxt/ \;
```

But it copies `.txt`  files folder by folder like below:

```
alltxt
  Dir_1
    a.txt
    x.doc
    b.txt
  Dir_2
    c.txt
  Dir_3
    d.txt
    e.txt
    y.doc
```

But How can I change my `rsync` command to work like my `cp` command?

Answer (score 2):

`rsync` has a flag, `--existing`, which will avoid copying files that does not already exist on the target:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' -exec rsync --existing {} "$HOME/alltxt/" ';'
```

I have also added `-type f` to make sure that `find` only finds *regular files*, and I have removed the `-R` flag (`--relative`) from `rsync` because I don't think it's useful in this case (using this flag is also the reason why you get the subdirectories on the target). I'm also using `$HOME` rather than `~` because I think it looks nicer.

You may also want to add `-a` (`--archive`) to the `rsync` invocation to preserve ownership and modification times etc.

A similar approach, but using `cp` instead of `rsync`:

```
find . -type f -name '*.txt' \
    -exec sh -c 'for n; do d="$HOME/alltxt/${n##*/}"; [ -f "$d" ] && cp "$n" "$d"; done' sh {} +
```

This finds all `.txt` files and calls a short shell script:

```
for n; do
    d="$HOME/alltxt/${n##*/}"
    [ -f "$d" ] && cp "$n" "$d"
done
```

This loop gets a number of `.txt` files from `find`. For each such name `n`, it creates the destination file path in `d`, checks whether the this path refers to an existing regular file and if so, copies the given file there.

Instead of the test `[ -f "$d" ]` you could use `[ "$d" -ot "$n" ]` which will be true if the destination file exists and is older than the found file. This is a nonstandard test but is supported by most shells.

The variable substitution `${n##*/}` will remove the directories from the path in `n`, so that `./some/path/file.txt` is turned into just `file.txt` (the base name).  It could be replaced by `$(basename "$n")`.

Answer (score 1):

```
shopt -s globstar
cp --update --target-directory targetDirectory sourceRootDir/**/*.txt
```

where:

- `shopt -s globstar` sets the extended globbing options, which include the `**` pattern
- `--target-directory` or `-t` gives a target directory to copy to (it can also be specified at the end of all the args, but it is often more readable to put it here in scripts).
- `--update` or `-u` makes `cp` copy the file only if the target is older i
  or non-existent.

Comment: The `-u` option would create new files. This is not what the user wants (as far as I understand it).

Comment: Also, there is (currently) no indication that the user is using GNU coreutils.